# Push UIWebView as detail view (table)

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I want to create a app, where I'll have say 10 table rows (list view) and each would have a detail view. Now for each detail view, I want to show 10 different remote htmls (in UIWebView)?

How do I do this? Should I use array to store the 10 URLs? How do I pass the URL from list to detail view?

Just to add: I also want to show an iAd on the detail view. So hope that can be easily integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a WebViewController that will act as the "detail view". Add a new `UIViewController` subclass to your project and just add a `UIWebView` and an `ADBannerView` to your nib file. Make an outlet for your webView and you should be good to go. From your list view, you can create a new detailViewController and load your row-specific url to the webView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString* url = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"];
    if (![url isEqualToString:@""]) {
        WebViewController* detailViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        [detailViewController release];
    }
}
```

This is a quick way to do that - you could create a custom -init method that accepts a url if you want. You should also use the methods of the `UIWebViewDelegate` in order to show some loading feedback/error message regarding the webView:

```
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView* webView;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for that...You have explained most of the things very nicely..I am thinking of going with the 1st approach..So just had a question regarding how exactly would I define the "dataArray" ? Just to add again, I want to show multiple .html files located remotely...http://mySite.com/page1.html ,.../page2.html,....../page5.html ...A +1 for now...

Comment: What about `NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mySite.com/page%i.html", indexPath.row];`

Comment: I guess that should work as well..Only thing I'll have to alter my naming convention from something very obvious like myTitlePage.html to page1.html...

Comment: Then populate your dataArray properly. For example, in your `-viewDidLoad` you can say something like `self.dataArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"www.site1.com", @"www.site2.com", @"www.site3.com", @"www.site4.com", nil];`

Comment: I did try the above code...But for some reasons, the detail view controller is not getting pushed....I added a breakpoint and it goes inside the pushViewController code....but still not pushing the detail UIWebViewController....Please let me know what I need to check...

Comment: Do I need to add anything to the detail WebViewController ....I have the outlet hooked up...

Answer (score 0):

You want the ability to pass data from one viewController to another viewController. The  correct way to do this is using Protocols and Delegates

Check out this example here - [Sharing data between view controllers and other objects](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/54859-sharing-data-between-view-controllers-other-objects.html) @ iPhone Dev SDK

Worked fine and allowed me to pass a string and an array forward and back between my views.

Comment: Thx a lot...I could not find the actual example where a List view pushes a UIWebView as detail view...